# Create DocuSign Envelope Error-DocuSignExtension.Model.Approve' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

When Creating Docusign envelope with Tab Type =  Approver and Tab Name = "some name" it fails for the following error

Create DocuSign Envelope Error-DocuSignExtension.Model.Approve' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

However, "Tab Type = Signer Attachment" with "Tab Name = "some name"" works without issue.

From the following documentation it does not state "Tab Name" is not supported with Tab Type = Approver

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/approvetab.html

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/#tab-types

Does anyone have documentation on "Tab Name" and if it can be used with "Tab Type Approver"? It could be I am missing something but just need confirmation if it is supported.

I am not able to provide the Request being sent because the Tool I am using to submit the Create Envelope API is unable to capture the Request so I just need confirmation if Tab Name can be used.

Thanks!

I have tested different types with Tab Name and it looks to be an issue specific to Tab Type Approver

[ConfigImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVHx8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Approve and Decline tabs do not have a "name" property available. This link to the REST API createTabs reference should show you all of the available properties for each different tab type. Most of them do have a name property, but there are a few exceptions like the Approve tab:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/create/

The name property is also set when you set a "tooltip" value in the UI. So a good rule of thumb is that if you can set a tooltip on a tab, it should have a name property.